# Schedule application Spring on Docker cluster

Tags: spring, docker, kubernetes, batch-processing, schedule

I need to schedule in batch my application Spring in a Docker cluster with different nodes.
I found the solution of set replicas=1 on docker-compose, but in my opinion this isn't the best solution because minimizes the potential of Docker.

Some help or advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to run several replicas of a spring application (it does not matter if this is managed by docker, k8s, it is standalone, etc). Then you want a background job to be started only on one single instance. Right? In this case I may advise you to have a look at [ShedLock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock).

> ShedLock does one and only one thing. It makes sure your scheduled
>   tasks are executed at most once at the same time. If a task is being
>   executed on one node, it acquires a lock which prevents execution of
>   the same task from another node (or thread). Please note, that if one
>   task is already being executed on one node, execution on other nodes
>   does not wait, it is simply skipped.

It integrates smoothly in Spring. For example a scheduled batch job may look like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = ...)
@SchedulerLock(name = "scheduledTaskName")
public void scheduledTask() {
   // do something
}
```

Various options may be used under the hood to implement a distributed lock, e.g. MySQL, Redis, Zookeeper and others.